# Github file ok in one machine but not working in another

Tags: git, eclipse, github

I have a `.svg` file that a fellow colleague committed to Github and I pulled at work for edits and committed. Some urgent edits where asked and now I'm editing the file from home, the file doesn't open in any svg editor or the browser at all, although it worked like a charm at work.

There isn't any diff between the files, deleting the entire repository from the machine and cloning it again does nothing and downloading the previous version neither. The only exception is if I download the file from the Github website instead of doing clone/pull. Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

I used git for eclipse for pulls, clones and commits. Maybe someone already experienced that?

Comment: Hi, whats the exception you are referring to? Does the `.svg` file works when you download it from Github web?

Comment: I believe git may make some changes to text files for compatibility reasons, like line endings for example. SVG files may be sensitive to this.

Comment: Yes, it works well if i download it from github web or github app or git, it looks like only the eclipse sync gives errors and as of now i am sure that when the file is updated elsewhere it isn't opening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying some other options (git from the command-line and GitHub client) i found that the culprit looks like eclipse git plugin. I don't know why, maybe some version incompatibility?

In the end the problem was that Eclipse configured the repository to use autocrlf and the files in question use \r\n, \n and \r with special meanings so changing even a \r\n to \n could corrupt the file.

The solution is to add the .svg to the .gitattribute with the -text parameter so crlf will not be converted to lf.